# StoryBoard Exception: Multiple animations in the same containing Storyboard

Tags: c#, animation, windows-8, storyboard, windows-store-apps

my windows store app storyboard throws in 6 out of 10 times following exception:

> WinRT information: Multiple animations in the same containing Storyboard cannot target the same property on a single element.

the code:

```
    private void Animate(int direction)
    {
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        foreach (var item in _tableList)
        {
            var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            var ease = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
            var animation = new DoubleAnimation { EasingFunction = ease, Duration = duration };
            if (direction == 0)
            {
                animation.From = 0;
                animation.To = _perUserColumnWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                animation.From = _perUserColumnWidth;
                animation.To = 0;
            }
            animation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, item);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Width");
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        }

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

I tried everything, but i can't get it work properly. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me like either you have multiple instances of the same item in `_tableList` or you're calling `Animate` in an asynchronous method and it's being called more than once.